# UI freezes when adding great amount of items to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I got a DataGrid which is getting filled with several items after an update function has been processed which is executed within a `BackgroundWorker`.

The `BackgroundWorker` actually requests a JSON API and parses the incoming response. In that process, the UI is not locked at all, everything is still responsive. Now, when filling the DataGrid with the previously fetched response, the UI locks and freezes until all items have been added.

Code:

Update method:

```
public override void Update()
{
    CanUpdate = false;
    AddEverythingButtonVisible = false;

    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Item.Search is sending a HTTP request, everything is responding
        foreach (Item item in Item.Search(_SearchText, _SearchLevelMin, _SearchLevelMax, _SearchRarity, _SearchType,_SearchRemoveUnavailable))
        {
            // after the response was parsed, the lock begins at this point when adding items by using the UI thread
            Execute(() => ItemCollection.Add(new ProfitItemViewModel(new ProfitItem(item))));
        }
     }
 }
```

`Execute` is a little helper function in order to access the UI thread while being in an seperate thread (BackgroundWorker) and looks as follows:

```
protected void Execute(System.Action action)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, action);
    }
}
```

I had a read about `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke` and came to the decision, that the UI thread must not stop responding when the actions are performed. So I ended up implementing `BeginInvoke` but the UI still freezes and locks when updating.

Well, is there any solution for not locking my entire application while my DataGrid is getting filled?

---

**Updated** and **working** code:

```
var searchResults = Item.Search(_SearchText, _SearchLevelMin, _SearchLevelMax, _SearchRarity, _SearchType, _SearchRemoveUnavailable);
var compiledSearchResults = searchResults.Select(item => new ProfitItemViewModel(new ProfitItem(item)));
foreach (ProfitItemViewModel item in compiledSearchResults)
    Execute(() => ItemCollection.Add(item));
```

Comment: I believe deadlock is the wrong term here.  The OP says deadlock, but mentions freezing and well and that it will eventually return.  That's not a deadlock, but simply freezing of the UI.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I fixed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding items individually, each as a separate invoke call, which would very much slow down the UI. Rather, add as many items as you can in a single UI call.  It may cause a temporary glitch, but will be much faster than a bunch of single calls.

Also, you are creating objects inside the UI call. If they aren't dependency objects, create them before you make the UI call to save some UI power as well.

Rule of thumb: do was much as you can outside the UI thread as you can, and only do work on the UI thread that has to be done on the UI thread (in your case, updating the ItemCollection).

Example:

```
var searchResult = Item.Search(_SearchText, _SearchLevelMin, _SearchLevelMax, _SearchRarity, _SearchType,_SearchRemoveUnavailable));

var compiledList = searchResult.Select(item => new ProfitItemViewModel(new ProfitItem(item))).ToArray();

Execute(() => {
    foreach (Item item in compiledList)
    {
        ItemCollection.Add(item);
    }
});
```

Also consider using DeferRefresh to speed up the adds like so:

```
Execute(() => {
    using(ItemCollection.DeferRefresh()) {
        foreach (Item item in compiledList)
        {
            ItemCollection.Add(item);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I justed tested this but sadly, it's as slow as it was before. Your tips are really good and I appreciate your help but even using DeferRefresh doesn't help. By the way, how about assigning the compiledList directly to ItemCollection? No looping would be needed here. I will edit my present code in a second.

Comment: 515 for now. Adding 30 items takes also as long as adding 515 items. Hm.

Comment: Ya, that's doesn't sound right. It shouldn't be that slow... Are there any list change events you are handling that may be slowing it down?

Comment: No. I just generated a testlist with 515 elements and adding that to my View also takes ages.

Comment: Try this. On your execute method, you are adding the items in the DataBind priority.  Try adding it at the Normal priority (which occurs before databinding). It may be that it's slow because you are adding items at the same time the binding engine is trying to run.

Comment: Wait a minute. I just found out that this only takes long when the application is first started. After pulling another set of items the second or third time, everything loads within 0.5 seconds. Do you know what this may cause?

Comment: Try using a simple list control rather than a data grid and see if it speeds up. It may be a problem with your data grid.

Comment: After a small refactoring everything works now as intended. I actually don't know where the error was since it is magically gone now. However, I decided to mark your answer as accepted because I really appreciate your tips and effort and because the solution might be in your answer. Really smart thinking, I will take these tips in consideration when I plan to do anything related to dispatchers in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load the items in another thread, and once loaded, then update the grid. For instance, I use a methdo like this:

```
public void LockAndDoInBackground(Action action, string text, Action beforeVisualAction = null, Action afterVisualAction = null)
{
    if (IsBusy)
        return;
    var currentSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    ActiveThread = new Thread((_) =>
    {                
        currentSyncContext.Send(t =>
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            BusyText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? "Wait please..." : text;
            if (beforeVisualAction != null)
                beforeVisualAction();
        }, null);
        action();
        currentSyncContext.Send(t =>
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            BusyText = "";
            if (afterVisualAction != null)
                afterVisualAction();
        }, null);
    });
    ActiveThread.Start();
}
```

`IsBusy` and `BusyText` are optional variables in the class (I use this method in a Base ViewModel Class)
The `action` parameter should be the load logic, and the `afterVisualAction` parameter should be the load data action in the grid. For instance:

**USAGE:**

```
public void Test()
{
    var tcollection = new List<ProfitItemViewModel>();
    Action tloadAction = ()=> 
    {
        foreach (Item item in Item.Search(_SearchText, _SearchLevelMin, _SearchLevelMax, _SearchRarity, _SearchType,_SearchRemoveUnavailable))
        {                
            tcollection.Add(new ProfitItemViewModel(new ProfitItem(item))));
        }
    };
    Action tupdateGridAction = ()=> 
    {
        foreach (Item item in tcollection)
        {                
            ItemCollection.Add(item);
        }
    };
    LockAndDoInBackground(tloadAction, "Generating Information...", null,  tupdateGridAction);
}
```

This is the idea I propose. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I believe that the problem lays not in fetching the items but in updating the View by pumping the new items into it. That part of the process is freezing the UI, not requesting the API.

Comment: Ok, :) it is just a tip